# joining on a query result

Tags: sql, join, teradata

i'm new to sql and having trouble joining a query result table with an existing table. i've been trying to name the query result as 
res_tab but it doesn't seem to work.i just want to be able to join the query result with an existing table. here's what i have so far:

```
(select distinct op_id
from cmpr_dept_vmdb.cust_promotion
where promo_id in ('TB4M40', 'TB4M41', 'TB4M42')
and regstrn_status_cd = 'R') as res_tab;

select elite_hist.op_id
from cmpr_dept_vmdb.elite_hist_detail as elite_hist
where elite_hist.instant_elt_promo_cd in ('F1', 'F2', 'F3')
inner join elite_hist
on res_tab.op_id = elite_hist.op_id
```

it's returning the following error: 
Syntax error: expected something between ')' and the 'as' keyword

Comment: When you go to a syntax summary, what is your justification for what you wrote? What is a [mcve] showing the problem? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help others make sense of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

SQL `select` syntax is

```
[SELECT] ...
[FROM] .....
[JOIN] ....
[WHERE] ....
[GROUP BY] .....
```

You seem like want to `join` like this.

```
select elite_hist.op_id
from cmpr_dept_vmdb.elite_hist_detail as elite_hist
inner join 
(
    select distinct op_id
    from cmpr_dept_vmdb.cust_promotion
    where promo_id in ('TB4M40', 'TB4M41', 'TB4M42')
    and regstrn_status_cd = 'R'
) as res_tab;
on res_tab.op_id = elite_hist.op_id
where elite_hist.instant_elt_promo_cd in ('F1', 'F2', 'F3')
```

Comment: I glad to help, you can mark this answer if that help you

Comment: @u356877  you can mark this answer if that help you

Answer (score 0):

You seems to want `subquery` with *correlation* approach correctly

```
select distinct elite_hist.op_id
from cmpr_dept_vmdb.elite_hist_detail as elite_hist
where instant_elt_promo_cd in ('F1', 'F2', 'F3') and 
      exists (select 1 
              from cmpr_dept_vmdb.cust_promotion as res_tab
              where res_tab.op_id = elite_hist.op_id and
                    res_tab.instant_elt_promo_cd in ('F1', 'F2', 'F3') and
                    res_tab.regstrn_status_cd = 'R
             );
```